# Beaglebone pin muxing modes

Tags: beaglebone-black

Can I use pins muxed to different modes on the same header using a device tree overlay?

E.g., could I take my [Beaglebone Black's P9 header](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1Nfmjqk8tAE/UzPt3gOf7HI/AAAAAAAAADM/ZsXz3Ag8T6M/s1600/pin+SPI+Beaglebone.PNG) and mux pins 28-31 to mode 3 for SPI, and pins 11-16 to mode 7 for GPIO? Or is it the case that must the entire P9 header be used in a single mode?

Comment: Based on this tutorial video, it looks like "yes": http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/beaglebone-gpio-programming-on-arm-embedded-linux/
Haven't tried it myself yet so I won't make this an answer.

Comment: I'm just getting started on my first Beaglebone design, and it sounds like you've got further than me in working out these details --- I don't really know enough to develop this into a full answer, but it sounds like you might be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *yes* you can use pins in whatever modes you want, as long as they don't interfere with on another.